# R tm package (version)

Tags: r, version, text-mining

I am starting a project of text mining using R and almost every resource I've found needs package `tm`, problem is, this package won't load because it imports package `slam` which is unavailable for R version 3.3.0.

- Does anyone know a good package for text mining other than this?
- Would it be suitable to downgrade my R version?

Comment: Update R. Slam requires 3.3.1 or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply updated to 3.3.1. This worked for me when I ran into the same thing last week on an OSX system running 3.3.1.   I used the method found here to save my packages, but to my delight I did not have to restore them (maybe bc it's only a minor version?): https://www.datascienceriot.com/how-to-upgrade-r-without-losing-your-packages/kris/

Once on 3.3.1, slam installed with no problems.

[Package Slam](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slam/slam.pdf)

Simply download the latest R installer and run it, and you should be good to go.